# Regular Expression Pattern for different strings to get as a group

Tags: regex, c#-4.0, regex-group

I have a string like this:

```
var stringToBeMatched = @"S14XV15011.MAXCV_MAXCV = 2323 /m BVASL /d {A1d} /t 2009.08.23 12:01:47 /a dfsd-df/c Imported from: HV2108C2; dfddf-er-author: TVI";
```

/d tag in above string can have any values from below:

```
a. /d MBX-JA-DVQ-1811
b. /d Bvala_Mana-CVw.xls
c. /d {A1dq}
d. /d MBX-JA-DVQ-1811 Control valves.pdf
e. /d MBEM306-0005 Data sheet 21P0001A_B_C
f. /d MBA-M30-PE-012-022 2.trinan sep.
```

I am using below pattern to match them but only options b & d get satisfied here:

```
var patternToCompare = @"(\{*(?<DocRef>(((\S\s*)+\.[a-zA-Z]+))|(\S\s*)+)\}*)";
```

If I add \w+ as an OR option at start, it matches above option c but not others. Kindly suggest the best possible pattern to match all above options.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Post the real sample input you pass to the regex engine, explain why your regex looks like it looks like (why use `(\S\s*)+`?) and provide the expected output.

Answer (score 0):

Your question sounds vague and complex. Without more examples it's only guess work. But this will match all the \d items

```
(^(MB)(A|X|EM).+)|({\A1.+})|(Bvala+.+\.xls)
```